# Error al auntentificar - ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

[image: Error]

Estimados al momento que me autentifico me genera este error, a que se debe gracias

Comment: Coloca el código que estás usando para autenticar. Visita estos enlaces para que veas cómo realizar una buena pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help Porque obtendrás una mejor respuesta si detallas el código, además de las configuraciones que usas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia, prueba porfa siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

Es un problema de la caché,  y es que el forgery-token se guarda información relativa a la sesión que hemos iniciado con el servidor, entre ellas el usuario logado. Al ser una petición GET el navegador intenta obtener ese token de la caché, pero el servidor se da cuenta de que ese token ha sido cargado de la caché del navegador y no ha sido generada en la petición actual, por lo que, para evitar ataques de Cross-Site Request Forgery, nuestro servidor (que es muy listo) dice: eh!, ¿a donde te crees que vas?

La solución para que el navegador no nos cargue ese token (y otras cosas) en las peticiones GET que hagamos cuando queremos logarnos es indicarlo en nuestro método de login. En un proyecto MVC4 por defecto, ese método está en la clase AccountController.cs

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   return View();
}
```

¿Cómo se lo indicamos?, añadiendo el atributo OutputCache de la siguiente manera:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   return View();
}
```

Si recompilamos y ejecutamos repitiendo el proceso de logarnos, navegar a la página anterior con el botón del navegador y haciendo clic en Login, ya no nos aparece el nombre de nuestro usuario anterior, sino que aparece vacío y podemos logarnos sin ningún problema y sin excepciones

adjunto la URL de donde he leido dicha solucion, saludos.

[Enlace Bibliografico](http://speakingin.net/2012/10/04/httpantiforgeryexception-en-asp-net-mvc/)

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Excelente hermano, voy a probar el codigo